# Typescript Class member function not accessible

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript, while working on an problem I created following class

```
export class ModuleInfoContainer extends Array<ModuleInfo>  {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  search(id: number) {
    let k: ModuleInfo;
    this.every(a => {
        k = a.search(id);
        return !k;
    });
    return k;
  }
}
```

I expected it to work, but while debugging, all array functions were accessible but member function `search` of `ModuleInfoContainer` was not accessible.
however after a few google searches i got an example, and ended up with this code

```
export class ModuleInfoContainer extends Array<ModuleInfo>  {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
search = function (id: number) {
    let k: ModuleInfo;
    this.every(a => {
        k = a.search(id);
        return !k;
    });
    return k;
  };
}
```

and it was working as expected.

what's wrong in first code?

**EDIT: `ModuleInfo` class**

```
export class ModuleInfo {
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
  DisplayName: string;
  ChildModules: ModuleInfoContainer;
  DependsOn: ModuleInfo[];
  parent: ModuleInfo;
  search(id: number): ModuleInfo {
    if (this.Id === id) {
        return this;
    } else if (this.ChildModules && this.ChildModules.length) {
        return this.ChildModules.search(id);
    }
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

This Is how I was trying to call this my search function:

```
let k = new ModuleInfoContainer();
k.search(1);
```

typescript compiles successfully but there is an error on runtime, saying `k does not have a member function named search`(error may not be exactly same as given by chrome but meaning was same).
however second code works fine.

Comment: how are you using it? I just made a playground example and it works fine.

Comment: I am using this code with angular 4, in chrome first one just says no function   search found. when i tried calling something like 
`let k = new ModuleInfoContainer();
k.search(1);` I have not debugged on any other browser.

Comment: Can you share the ModuleInfo class?

Comment: I have updated question with ModuleInfo class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I find these links

1. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13720
2. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-work

So it was a known issue of typescript when targeting ES5 or lower.